# Live document editing & colaboration

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, conceptual

For university project I'm rolling out some cloud document editor. One of the features is to give possibility for multiple users to edit it in real time. Question is how to approach this?

I know google docs, are doing some advanced DOM manipulations behind the scene, but if I had just simple plain textarea what its the best way to sync changes, merge them behind the scene and update it on user frontend. I'd be using rails, mongoid and js/jquery.

Any ideas how this could be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just recently did some research on what is available.
You could check out etherpad lite to analyze their approach. Basically the use a client-server architecture.

https://github.com/Pita/etherpad-lite

Comment: Thanks, this looks good enough for a starting point. I have to do some research on it but it's promising.